# Structure pointer behaving weirdly

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, structure

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct stu {
    int roll;
    struct stu *next;
} stu1;

int main() {
    stu1.roll = 1;
    
    struct stu *head = &stu1; // Question about this line
    head->next = &stu1;

    printf("Address of Head : %p, Head->Next : %p, Head->Data : %d\n", 
           &head, head->next, head->roll);
    printf("\nAddress of stu : %p,Stu->Next : %p, Stu->Data : %d", 
           &stu1, stu1.next, stu1.roll);

    return 0;
}
```

So the line where I have declared the head pointer to structure, when I assign it as `struct stu * head = &stu1;` it just runs fine the whole program runs fine, but when I write `struct stu * head;` or `struct stu * head = NULL;` the program says segmentation fault.

I don't understand like what's the difference in them and ig when using Linked List, I would have to assign head as `Head->next = headnode` not as `Head = &Headnode`.

Comment: You haven't actually declared a stu1 variable. stu1 is a type according to latest (as of now) code.

Comment: @Syntactics Actually, they have declared a variable.  Its type is `struct stu` and the variable is called `stu1`.  Refer to the declaration: `struct stu { int roll; struct stu *next; } stu1;`  Perhaps you're used to the C idiom of using `typedef` where the declaration would be `typedef struct stu { int roll; struct stu *next; } MyTypeName;`  But there is no `typedef` in the provided code.

Answer (score 3):

If you try to dereference a null pointer or uninitialized pointer, you get undefined behavior. A segmentation fault is one possible result of this.

If you write:

```
struct stu *head = NULL; 
head->next = &stu1;
```

Then `head` doesn't actually point *to* anything. Bear in mind that `head->next` is equivalent to `(*head).next`.

Comment: I am not dereferencing any pointer, all I was trying was to put the address of stu1 into head->next.

Comment: @DataScientisttobe: `head->next` is identical to `(*head).next`. You are dereferencing `head`.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare:

```
struct stu *head;
```

...then `head` is a pointer.  If you leave it uninitialized you will get undefined behaviour when you dereference it with `head->next`.  If you initialize it to NULL then you will also get undefined behaviour because you are attempting to dereference a NULL pointer.

But if you properly initialize `head` to be a pointer to some valid `struct stu` then things will go as planned.

```
struct stu *head = &stu1; // this is legal
head->next = &stu1; // this is also legal
```

Be aware that the code above, as you wrote it, is legal, but sets up a closed cycle where `stu1`'s `next` pointer points right back to `stu1`.

Comment: Well for that I can just do `stu1->next = NULL` that would be alright na

Comment: @DataScientisttobe No.  `stu1` is not a pointer, so `stu1->next` will result in a compile error.  You may, however, write `stu1.next`.  And you may do `stu1.next = NULL;`.  After assigning `struct stu *head = &stu1;` then you may also perform `head->next = NULL;` to accomplish the same thing because `head` points to `stu1`.

Comment: Well after `struc stu *head = &stu1` both the head->next & stu1.next always points to same thing either NULL of &stu1. I want them to point different like `head->next = &stu1` and `stu1.next = NULL`.

Comment: But `head` **is** a pointer to `stu1` as you've initialized it.  You want a linked list with one node, right?  Go ahead and write `head = &stu1` and then write either `head->next = NULL` or `stu1.next = NULL` whichever you prefer because their effects are equivalent - they both modify the exact same variable: the `next` pointer of the `stu1` structure.  `head` should just be a pointer to "the first node of the list", which is `stu1` or `head` can be NULL if the list is empty (contains no nodes).

Comment: I created one more variable of structure assigned it to head while declaring head and now I can do `head->next = &stu1` & `stu1.next = NULL`. Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

A *segfault* is an access violation error, it occurs if one tries to access a restricted area of memory.

Constructs like

```
//declaration without initialization
struct stu *head; //undefined

//declaration with initialization
struct stu *head = NULL; //points to NULL
```

cannot be dereferenced, every attempt like

```
head->next;
```

will result in a segfault or at least undefined behaviour.

On the other hand, if you point to a valid region of memory, like

```
struct stu *head = &stu1;
```

then

```
head->next;
```

will return the address stored in `next` (which could be uninitialized, point to NULL or a valid object, so be careful dereferencing that).

---

Could be off topic, but if you want to implement a (single) linked list, then a logical approach would be to have two separated types

e.g.

```
//item type
struct item {
    int data;          //data storage
    struct item *next; //pointer to next item
};

//list type
struct list {
    //unsigned int size; //number of items in list
    struct item *head;   //first item in list
    struct item *tail;   //last item in list
};
```

then

```
//define some items
struct item item1 = {1, NULL};
struct item item2 = {2, NULL};
//...

//start with an empty list
struct list lst = {/*0,*/ NULL, NULL};
//add item 1
lst.head = &item1; //first item points to item1
lst.tail = &item1; //last item points to item1
//++lst.size;      //increase list size
//add item2
lst.tail->next = &item2; //set next of current last item to item2
lst.tail = &item2;       //set item2 as last item
//++lst.size;            //increase list size
//...
```

Comment: `struct stu *head = &stu1;` runs fine without any fault but the thing with that is `head->next` & `stu1->next` are always pointing to same thing either `NULL` or `&stu1`. I want `head->next = &stu1` & `stu1.next = NULL`.

Comment: If `head` points to `stu1`, then you can write `head->next = &stu1;` (or `stu1.next = NULL` but that is independent from `head`), the important part here is that `head` must point to a valid object. By only declaring `head` without initialization/definition (or pointing to `NULL`), you cannot dereference `head`, otherwise you'll end up with UB or a segfault.